# Cycle through search results in alacritty terminal

Tags: alacritty

Currently I can search the console buffer in alacritty using Ctrl+Shift+F, which highlights all matching results. However its not clear for me how to jump back and forth between the results? In vim for example you can do this with n for next match and N for previous. Is there something similar in alacritty?

Comment: Forward cycle is possible by Return key, however, I still don't know how to cycle backwards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- For scroll to next, you can use `Enter`
- For scroll to previous, you can use `Shift+Enter`

Another list of actions described below:

```sh
# Search Mode
#- { key: Return,                mode: Search|Vi,  action: SearchConfirm         }
#- { key: Escape,                mode: Search,     action: SearchCancel          }
#- { key: C,      mods: Control, mode: Search,     action: SearchCancel          }
#- { key: U,      mods: Control, mode: Search,     action: SearchClear           }
#- { key: W,      mods: Control, mode: Search,     action: SearchDeleteWord      }
#- { key: P,      mods: Control, mode: Search,     action: SearchHistoryPrevious }
#- { key: N,      mods: Control, mode: Search,     action: SearchHistoryNext     }
#- { key: Up,                    mode: Search,     action: SearchHistoryPrevious }
#- { key: Down,                  mode: Search,     action: SearchHistoryNext     }
#- { key: Return,                mode: Search|~Vi, action: SearchFocusNext       }
#- { key: Return, mods: Shift,   mode: Search|~Vi, action: SearchFocusPrevious   }
```